# floating-point constant comparison - (0.0 ? 1 : 0)

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, floating-point

In the example below, if uncomment `float f = 0.0;`,
 and replacing the `return(0.0 ? 1 : 0);` with `return(f ? 1 : 0);`.
The output is `NIL`.

Here is my code:

```
/* file main.c 
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86
cl -W4 -MTd -O2 -TC main.c -Fetest */   
#include <stdio.h>    
int my_func(void)
{
   /* float f = 0.0; */
   return(0.0 ? 1 : 0);
}
int main(void)
{  
    printf("%s\n", ( my_func() ? "ONE" : "NIL") );
    return 0;
}
```

On a 32-bit Windows machine, using Visual Studio this code outputs  :

```
ONE
```

- Why `my_func()` returns value `true` (1)  ?
- How does the C compiler interpret this expression `(0.0 ? 1 : 0)` ?

Comment: Is this actually a real-world problem you face? Is this the sort of thing you're likely to do in real code? :-)

Comment: I just ran the same code and got "NIL"

Comment: Just a shot in the dark -- maybe your compiler is comparing hex values without truncating? ex. (int) 0 is equivalent to 0x000000, but with floating point precision, you likely wont land on that exact value

Comment: What does `printf("%.56f\n", 0.0);` give you?

Comment: I read similar discussion on the web and I do not understand why `" 0.0 is TRUE "`, or this is a bug of VC compiler.
@jxh On a 32-bit Windows - `0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: Better yet -- run `printf("%x", 0.0);` and you should get a better representation

Comment: It's not a bug.  You should never assume 0.0 == 0 exactly.

Comment: @Jim, shouldn't `0.0` when converted to `bool` always become `false` no matter what the internal representation is? If it's a normal integer conversion it should truncate to `0`.

Comment: @John why would `printf("%x", 0.0)` give a better presentation?  0.0 is a double, typically 8 bytes.  %x directive it looking for an `int` which is typically 4 bytes.

Comment: @chux because the return type is an int.

Comment: @John are your referring to the return of the `printf()`?  The is _no_ other return type in the statement `printf("%x", 0.0);`

Comment: @chux My bad, got mixed up. I've looked at too much code today. Evaluating `0.0` in a conditional should compare to `0`, but again, I'm not sure if that depends on the compiler (may or may not truncate)

Comment: [check this](http://ideone.com/KBUb2H)

Comment: @John: `printf("%x", 0.0)` has undefined behavior, since `%x` requires an `unsigned int` argument; `unsigned int` and `double` probably aren't even the same size on the system in question. `"%a"` prints a floating-point value in a hexadecimal format, but Visual Studio may not support it.

Comment: You could always hit up the [VisualC/C++ team on Twitter](https://twitter.com/visualc); they seem to be fairly responsive.

Comment: @John: The C standard's requirements on floating-point *might* be loose enough to permit the constant `0.0` to be treated as non-zero (I'm not quite sure about that), but Windows systems use IEEE floating-point which doesn't permit that kind of imprecision. If `0.0` is being treated as non-zero by Visual Studio, it's not because VS is taking advantage of the ISO C standard's lax requirements for floating-point; it's because there's a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: @KeithThompson: it happens before the source makes it to the optimizer and the FP model stuff in the case of a literal `0.0`, but only for ternary operators (and in any context it appears). If you in any way change the context from `0.0 ? 1 : 0`, like `(y = 0.0) ? 1 : 0`, the error goes away. Therefore, I think you're safe to say VS does not *mean* to treat it as non-zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the Microsoft compiler which you should submit to [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio). I was able to duplicate it in Visual Studio Express 2010, but not in gcc: http://ideone.com/8qPRJd.

Any expression that evaluates to an integer value of `0` should be equivalent to `false`. This is exactly how it's working with the `float` variable, and it's the same when I tried it with a `double` as well.

Comment: I concur.  (BTW beat me by 3 minutes)

Comment: Note that no conversion to an integer type occurs in float_expr : expr1 : expr2. Instead, the first expression of a conditional expression is required to have scalar type, and is compared to the zero of that type (6.5.15:4 in C11). if (0.5) printf(…); does print (and if (-0.0) printf(…); doesn't).

Comment: Even with `/Od` you can check the assembly listing...it straight removes the `(0.0 ? 1 : 0)` and adds `mov eax, 1`. I'd say a bug. Placing a literal `0.0` in an if-expr causes the appropriate assembly to be generated (even with optimizations).

Comment: @user7116 I was also able to validate that Visual Studio 2012 works the same, although I don't have the latest service pack.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Right. More precisely, the first operand is compared for equality to `0`, which is of type `int`. Comparing a `double` to an `int` causes the `int` to be converted to `double.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I tried 2k10 and 2k12, both produce valid assembly in all other contexts than the ternary expression. If you add a simple expression, like `0.0 != 0`, the correct assembly is generated (`/O2` or `/Od`). Definitely seems to be a failing optimization (also not related to fp mode).

Comment: "Any expression that evaluates to an integer value of 0 should be equivalent to `false`" -- True, but incomplete. Any expression that *compares equal to 0* is false. `0.0` doesn't evaluate to an integer value of 0 (or to any other integer value), but it does compare equal to `0`. (The comparison converts the `int` value `0` to `double`.)

Answer (score 0):

return(0.0 ? 1:0) compiled to a fixed return 1.  In the other case, the floating point variable was actually assessed, and 0.0 did not equate to 0.